# What causes Linux to issue a CLEAR_TT_BUFFER command?

Tags: linux, usb, libusb

I'm writing a library that interfaces to a *[Full Speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_1.x)* USB device using libusb. It seens to be working fine, but when I run the code inside GDB or [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind), I see in [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) that there are CLEAR_TT_BUFFER commands being send to the USB hub (I presume it's the internal one, since I have the device directly attached to the PC), and some packets seem to be lost (this shouldn't happen, as I'm using bulk transfer).

So the question is, what (under which conditions) is issuing those commands, and how do I prevent/detect them?